# Using C++ Macro with arguments into a linked piece of code

Tags: c++, debugging, macros, linker

i have a macro that i use to speed up the implementation of Factory classes.
For example, to build a Factory for a CameraGenerator i use the macro this way: 

    `GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_START(CameraGenerator) 

       ... do some stuff ...                       

    GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_END(CameraGenerator)`

This build AND ALSO INSTANTIATE a class named CameraGeneratorFactory. All this is done into the .cpp file, not in the .h, so that the particural instance of the Factory become a global variable but the particular factory definition is not available outside of this file. All factories inherits from a base Factory class.

The problem comes when in another .cpp i need to define and instantiate another particular Factory, say FileGeneratorFactory, so i do

`GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_START(FileGenerator) 

       ... do some other stuff ...                       

    GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_END(FileGenerator)`

when compiled in DEBUG, the second use of this macro executes again the "CameraGenerator" Factory constructor, not the correct "FileGenerator" Factory one, like if once the macro had been preprocessed, compiled and linked into the first .cpp, it is always executed with the same argument. I repeat, **the issue is only when compiled in debug mode**.

Does anyone know something about this behaviour?

thanks in previous

Here is the code of the macro:

```
#define GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_START(GEN_NAME) \
    class GEN_NAMEFactory : public AbstractGeneratorFactory{                             \
    public:                                                                              \
       GEN_NAMEFactory() : AbstractGeneratorFactory(){                                   \

#define GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_CONF_SECTION(GEN_NAME) \
           extern GeneratorBuilder generator_builder;                                    \
           generator_builder.add_factory(#GEN_NAME, this);                               

#define GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_END_CONF_SECTION(GEN_NAME) \
       }                                                                                 \
       GEN_NAMEFactory(const GEN_NAMEFactory& f) : AbstractGeneratorFactory(f){}         \
       GEN_NAMEFactory& operator=(const GEN_NAMEFactory& f){                             \
           if (this == &f) return *this;                                                 \
           AbstractGeneratorFactory::operator =(f);                                      \
           return *this;                                                                 \
       }                                                                                 \
       virtual ~GEN_NAMEFactory(){}                                                      \
       virtual Generator* build() const{                                                 \
           return new GEN_NAME();                                                        \
       }                                                                                 \
       Generator* build(const Configuration& cfg) const throw(bad_parameter) {           \
            Generator* g = 0;                                                            \

#define GENERATOR_BUILD_FACTORY_END(GEN_NAME) \
            return g;                                                                    \
        }                                                                                \
    };                                                                                   \
    GEN_NAMEFactory instance_of_GEN_NAMEFactory;
```

Comment: Macros don't exist at the link stage, so what's happening is a bit too strange to just guess from the description given. Seeing the code for the macro might help.

Comment: Any reason why you don't make it a template?

Comment: Obviously yes. It will be exported in python. More in general, templates absolutely don't suite to problem that i am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `GEN_NAMEFactory` you need to use `GEN_NAME##Factory` inside of macro. Otherwise your code violates ODR rule (you define GEN_NAMEFactory in a different ways in two compilation units). This is causing a trouble only in debug, as only in debug the functions are not inlined, and only one of the two conflicting implementations of GEN_NAMEFactory is used when linking. You would easily see the conflict if you tried to expand both factories in one source file.

As an alternative (or in addition to) you could use anonymous namespace around the factory to limit the scope of the identifier to one source.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed! I rarely use macros and i didn't know the correct syntax.

Comment: If it worked for you, it would be nice if you can "accept" the answer by checking the green check box. If you still think there is something to add, just ask and I will try to help.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use such macros, they're evil.

You *might* find it helpful to instead implement your generic factory code as a C++ template.

But I suspect that the whole thing is totally misguided, for those macros, it's like seeing someone building an airplane and using a hammer to drive in the screws. Then, one tends to strongly suspect that it won't help to suggest using a screwdriver instead of the hammer. For chances are, when asked what the airplane is *for*, the person will reply with some purpose that an airplane is decidedly not an appropriate solution for.

Cheers & hth.,